# uploading image using 1 input file only, using ajax,jquery and php

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

So I have this scenario.

I have a form and in that form there is a button which will add the information in my table, but will not send it yet to the server. There is also a input file which must reset on each click on "Add" button.

The problem is, how can I make this images present to the $_FILES global variable in php when i var_dump it? Any ideas will be much appreciated, thank you very much!

So this is what i've already done on my javascript

```
$('#add-violator').click(function(){
   var ft = $('#img-upload')[0].files[0];
   images.push(ft);
});

//on ajax call I added.
formdata.append("images", images);
```

Comment: It's always good to include a some code sample

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't exist to write the code, please provide something for people to work off.

Comment: @John Sorry guys, just new to stackoverflow, I edited my question.